# run 100 model at once, instead of manually one by one

Tags: r

i created this table.

```
    dat <- matrix(rbinom(6*100, 6, 0.5), ncol=6)
```

then use one row from at the table to fill the 'size' statement to train the model.

```
    nn.sizes <- dat[1,]
    sample.number <- length(dat2[[1]][,1])
    nns <- lapply(1:length(dat2), function(i){nn <- nnet(dat2[[i]][1:(sample.number),], dat3[[i]][(twindow+1):(length(dat3[[i]]))],size=nn.sizes[i], linout = TRUE)})
```

my question is, i only know how to do it manually one by one, it means i have to run 100 times.  Is there a way to run it once

Comment: Wrap that in `apply(dat, 1, .....)` and it will run row-by-row for each row until you run out of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `replicate()` and only create a single vector on each replication, instead of looping over a matrix.  This just loops the expression block (code between the `{}` braces), evaluating it 100 times.

```
replicate(100, { 
    nn.sizes <- rbinom(6, 6, 0.5)

    <the rest of your code here> 

})
```